# Почему QProcess выводит некорректный результат?

Tags: c++, python, qt, процесс

Необходимо с помощью QProcess запустить скрипт, написанный на питоне. Скрип принимает на ввод два значения, после чего выводит результат. Никаких промежуточных выводов скрипт не делает. 
Скрипт скомпилирован в .exe файл

Код у меня для этого следующий (С++):

```
QProcess process(this);
process.start("Translator.exe");
process.waitForStarted(-1);
process.write("Table\n");
process.waitForBytesWritten(); //Не совсем уверен в именно такой расстановке этих функций
process.write("en-ru\n"); 
process.waitForBytesWritten(); //Однако от изменения их расположения ничего не меняется
process.waitForReadyRead();
qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
process.closeWriteChannel();
process.kill();
```

Я вызываю kill(), так как скрипт по завершению ожидает ввода чего угодно, чтобы закрыть программу

Проблема, собственно, в чём: скрипт должен вывести "Стол" (Это переводчик). Однако вместо этого выводится: "\xD2\xE0\xE1\xEB\xE8\xF6\xE0\r\n" и никакие манипуляции это исправить не могут.

Дополнительно кидаю код на питоне:

```
import requests 
import json

def getTranslate(text, lang_code = 'en-ru'):
    url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?'
    key = 'trnsl.1.1.20190227T075339Z.1b02a9ab6d4a47cc.f37d50831b51374ee600fd6aa0259419fd7ecd97'
    lang = lang_code; 
    r = requests.post(url, data={'key': key, 'text': text, 'lang': lang})  
    return json.loads(r.text)['text'][0]

txt = input();#Сюда вводится "Table"
lang = input();#Здесь "en-ru"

print(getTranslate(txt, lang)) //Тут я ожидаю получить "Стол"
input();
```

Наперёд говоря, скрипт работает правильно, впрочем, как и .exe.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что идёт не так?

Comment: Решил ради интереса вот что попробовать:  собрал тестовый проект на C++. Программа просто принимает на вход число и выводит его увеличенное на 1. Такая вещь вполне работает, как надо. Что не так с питоном, это ведь в обоих случаях просто exe в командной строке?

Comment: Может, дело в кодировке? Но ведь это абсолютно не похоже на какую-либо известную кодировку

Comment: Кажется, я напал на след. Если сменить весь текст на английский, то заранее выводимый текст в коде питона будет отображаться нормально. Значит, дело в том, что не распознаются русские символы. Но кто именно их не распознаёт?

Comment: Может быть, QProcess не может с ними работать? Вряд ли. Тогда как быть?

Comment: Стал больше склоняться к версии, что дело в QProcess, однако fromUtf8() не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Исчёрпывающее решение находится тут: [Как установить правильную кодировку в QProcess?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105456/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-qprocess/1105517#1105517)

Эта моя собственная тема. Там я задавал более конкретный вопрос.