# Как установить правильную кодировку в QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt

Проблема в том, что QProcess считывает вывод процесса, однако, если там есть русские символы, он их отображает в виде вопросительных знаков либо других иероглифов (зависит от того, какие манипуляции с ним проводить). Итог один: английский язык - отлично, русский - плохо.

Программа, из которой он читает, написана на питоне, там, вроде, с кодировкой всё отлично (так как программа сама по себе работает нормально).

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы QProcess читал русские символы (желательно, чтобы он их ещё и записывал)

Этот вопрос - продолжение предыдущуего, в нём вся конкретика. Там же в комментариях я вёл размышления: [Почему QProcess выводит некорректный результат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105334/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-qprocess-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82)

Comment: по моему это почти ваш случай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074969/printing-unicode-through-a-qprocess

Comment: К сожалению, хотя по сути проблема там та же, мне это особо не помогло, ведь там PyQt, и те советы я не могу применить к своей программе. Но стоит отметить, что мой питон код написан в соответствии с советами из той темы.

Comment: Ура! Есть продвижки. На этом форуме я нашёл, как можно исправить проблему с чтением: https://forum.rosalinux.ru/viewtopic.php?t=3374. Если обернуть функцию readAll() в QString::fromLocal8Bit(), то всё заработает. Сейчас разбираюсь с вводом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Целый день мне на это понадобился. Методом проб и ошибок, а так же рытья в интернете и документации я смог решить эту задачу.

Для ввода русских символов в поток:

```
QString str = "Нужная строка\n";
std::string tstring = str.toLocal8Bit().data();
const char *str_char = tstring.c_str(); //str_char уже можно записывать в QProcess
```

Для вывода русских символов из потока:

```
qDebug() << QString::fromLocal8Bit(process.readAll());
```

Всё. Решено.